# How to load a website (html and javascript) with the [Android-Web-Server](https://github.com/sonuauti/Android-Web-Server)

Tags: javascript, android, html, web, webserver

I have a website that can be loaded only on a web-server. I need to load it offline on Android.
How can I load the website with [Android-Web-Server](https://github.com/sonuauti/Android-Web-Server)?

The website file structure:

[image: Website files]

I have already tried opening the website directly in WebView, but it didn't work. Loading it from a web server like Xampp was successful.
Of course, this website does not include PHP.

*I don't have any problem with starting web server. I don't know how can i load a website (make root path of web server in my website folder that contains index.htm) and then load browser with url http://localhost:9000/index.htm*

Comment: What are your specific errors or where are you getting stuck in their guides for setup?

Comment: I don't have any problem with starting web server. I don't know how can i load a website (make root path of web server in my website folder that contains index.htm) and then load browser with url http://localhost:9000/index.htm

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to start a webserver? You can use a WebViewClient() then pass the file there `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.htm")`

Comment: @MH-Rouhani (and @Alex) From their docs and it becomes clear that the intention of the library is not for you to store the website on your computer, but inside (or accessible by) your android app itself. The idea is for your app to then provide/generate a url the user of it can use on their computer/device to access feature(s) of the app.

Comment: The website only can run on a web server. I am not very professional in web concepts. but I am sure about this subject. >>> Loading it from a web server like Xampp was successful.

Comment: @MH-Rouhani There is absolutely no need to run a webserver on Android.  If you think you need to, you don't know what you're actually doing.  In addition, you're looking at a project that hasn't had any checking in 5 years.  It's a dead project.  I would be shocked if it worked and compiled given the changes in Android in the past half decade.

Comment: @GabeSechan Such an ability can be useful. There's an app on my phone that exposes a local url that allows me to connect to it over wifi to then transfer files between my computer and the phone. The local url I access from my browser, outside of the phone. As another example, think about whats going on when a router exposes a local url for setup purposes, presented as a web page.

Comment: @GetSet It really isn't.  Android is not meant to be a server OS, background processing limitations make it useless as one.  And there's never a good reason to have a webserver on localhost just to display a webpage, over just displaying the webpage directly.  Even your examples have better ways of doing things (for example, just connect your phone and use file transfer that's built into Android).

Comment: @GetSet A router is a totally different scenario.  1)It isn't running Android.  2) It's being accessed from a separate piece of hardware over a network.  This isn't the case here, he's trying to show a website on his own device.

Comment: @GabeSechan I prefer the Wifi way for file transfer since I dont have to plug and unplug usb and so forth. I 1st started using it because I had some phones with jacks that were getting jacked up. ... As far as OP's apparent misunderstanding of what the library is for, there does appear to be that.

Comment: @GetSet Bluetooth transfer to the PC also works.  And is far more secure than running a webserver, which anyone on the network could access

Comment: Anyone on your local network. The phone itself would be connected to your Wifi for all of this to work. You could share it over a public network, if one liked. ... Anyway I was just pointing out valid use cases for such a library. I plan on investigating it further, its useful.